# PostgreSQL does not choose my indexes well

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

```
create table public.tabla
(
    cod_tabla bigint not null,
    tabla varchar(31) not null,
    constraint pk_tabla primary key (cod_tabla)
);


create table public.entidad
(
    cod_entidad bigint not null,
    cod_tabla bigint not null,
    cod_entidad_tabla bigint not null,
    constraint pk_entidad primary key (cod_entidad),
    constraint fk_tabla_entidad foreign key (cod_tabla)
        references public.tabla (cod_tabla) match simple
        on update cascade
        on delete cascade
);


CREATE INDEX idx_tabla_entidad
    ON public.entidad USING btree
    (cod_tabla ASC NULLS LAST);

CREATE INDEX idx_entidad_tabla_4
    ON public.entidad USING btree
    (cod_entidad_tabla ASC NULLS LAST)
    INCLUDE(cod_entidad, cod_tabla, cod_entidad_tabla)
    WHERE cod_tabla::bigint = 4;
```

[image]

I think postgresql doesn't use the index idx_entidad_tabla_4,
Postgresql is sequentially scanning the entire table applying the where condition

```
explain (analyze, buffers, format text) select * from entidad where cod_tabla = 4


Index Scan using idx_tabla_entidad on entidad  (cost=0.56..51121.41 rows=1405216 width=20) (actual time=0.037..242.609 rows=1409985 loops=1)
  Index Cond: ((cod_tabla)::bigint = 4)
  Buffers: shared hit=12839
Planning Time: 0.158 ms
Execution Time: 311.828 ms
```

[image]

```
SELECT count(*) from entidad;
34.413.354

SELECT count(*) from entidad where cod_tabla = 4;
1.409.985
```

My questions are:

- Why doesn't it use the index idx_entidad_tabla_4?
- How could I force its use?

Comment: psql (PostgreSQL) 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-2.pgdg18.04+1)

Comment: select * from entidad where cod_tabla = 4

Comment: Index Scan using idx_tabla_entidad on entidad as entidad (rows=1409985 loops=1)
Index Cond: ((cod_tabla)::bigint = 4)

Comment: Is the table well-vacuumed?  If not, an index-only scan will not appear very enticing.  compare relallvisible to relpages in pg_class.

Comment: What exactly should I do?

Comment: `select relpages, relallvisible from pg_class where relname='entidad'` and then `VACUUM VERBOSE ANALYZE entidad`

Comment: After VACUUM FULL FREEZE VERBOSE ANALYZE public.entidad; everything remains the same

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) (not as a screenshot) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Do not put the plan into comments, [edit] your question.